# Regex to match string in html

Tags: regex

I'm trying to get the position of a substring in an HTML. The hard part is that the html might be inside the substring.

Ex:
If I want to match `2nd`, but in the html, it's coded as follow `2<span class="super">nd</span>`.

Note: It can be any substring, not just "1st", "2nd", ...

How can have a request that match any kind of inline HTML balise?

Comment: You can look for a regex match, but take only parts of it, using [capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution:

`sub = r'\b' + '(<span[^>]*>)?'.join(list(substring)) + r'\b'`

So:
`2nd` is transformed into `\b2(<span[^>]*>)?n(<span[^>]*>)?d\b`

Which match
`2nd` and `2<span class="super">nd</span>`